# how to take a key value pair from array of objects and create a new object from that key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having a array of object which I want to convert into object with key as the array of object's key's value and value as array of object's value's value.

Suppose I have an array like this

```
let arr = [
{name: "abcd", value: "xyz"},
{name: "pqr", value: "uvw"},
....
]
```

I want to create an object from this array like this.

```
obj = {
abcd: "xyz",
pqr: "uvw",
...
}
```

I want to take the value of the key and value and use them to create a new object. Is there any way to do this.?

Comment: _"Is there any way...?"_ - Yes. What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Do you know for sure that `arr` will not containt two or more items with the same `name`? And, you can have two items with the same `name`, what would the output object expected to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [
  {name: "abcd", value: "xyz"},
  {name: "pqr", value: "uvw"}
]
const result = {}
arr.forEach((element) => {
  result[element.name] = element.value
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two *main* different ways I see you could achieve this fairly easily:

### 1. The .reduce() method

```js
let arr = [
  {name: "abcd", value: "xyz"},
  {name: "pqr", value: "uvw"},
  // ...
];

obj = arr.reduce((a,c) => (a[c.name] = c.value, a), {});

console.log(obj);
```

### 2. The Object.values() and Object.fromEntries() method

```js
let arr = [
  {name: "abcd", value: "xyz"},
  {name: "pqr", value: "uvw"},
  // ...
];

obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(e => Object.values(e)));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with `reduce`. The `reduce` uses an aggregator function and expects an initial value. You can supply the initial value as an empty object and provide the aggregator function as mentioned below:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "abcd", value: "xyz"},
  {name: "pqr", value: "uvw"}
];

const result = arr.reduce((a, x) => {
    return {
      ...a,
      [x.name]:x.value
    }
}, {});

console.log(result);
```